# WHY Julia can't work in Atom?

Tags: julia

I have installed Atom and julia 1.0.0, the julia-client and uber-juno all installed,but why it cant run ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihsTH.jpg)

Comment: maybe the reason is the pakge of Atom not compared the julia 1.0.0, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juno supports Julia v0.7 for now, not v1.0 yet. Please install Julia v0.7 as it provides the same new features as v1.0 and not yet removed the deprecated ones from v0.6.x.